# Is there a way to move a channel to a category based of category name using a custom bot

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am new to to Discord.Net API and got quite a hang of it. But i am having issues moving a channel created by a bot, to an existing category channel. If i can just use the channel ID that would be ok, but ideal it would find a category named 'user-reports' and get the ID from that to set the channel parent or position.

```cs
//This is what i have to create a channel for testing purposes
var test = await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("HI");

//I used this previously to find if a message was sent in a specific channel then it would act
 if (Context.Channel.Name != "report-user")
            {
                await Context.User.SendMessageAsync(Context.User + " You have tried to send a ticket to the wrong channel. Please use the report-user channel");
                return;
            }
```

Comment: You can assign the channel category during channel creation by utilizing the second parameter of the `CreateTextChannelAsync` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
    //Find the ID for the desired category 
    var categoryId = Context.Guild.CategoryChannels.FirstOrDefault(category => category.Name.Equals("user-reports"))?.Id;

    //Set channel category during channel creation
    await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("Hi", prop => prop.CategoryId = categoryId);

    //Set channel category after channel creation
    var channel = await Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync("Hello");
    await channel.ModifyAsync(prop => prop.CategoryId = categoryId);
```

Comment: Thanks that got it working. when I was trying that in the past I got stuck up on getting  the categoryID so nothing else was working and I assumed I was doing the entire thing wrong. I missed the FirstOrDefaut